# azure-arm-consumption: get consumption with a CSP subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-resource-manager

In my Node.js project I am trying to use [azure-arm-consumption package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-consumption) to get the current consumption/billing.

My code:

```
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');
MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(keys.appId, keys.pass, keys.tenantId);
const { ConsumptionManagementClient } = require('azure-arm-consumption');
const client = new ConsumptionManagementClient (credentials, subscriptionId);
const cost = client.forecasts.list(subscriptionId);
```

The last line throws an error saying that this method only works for an EA subscription (which makes sense, I use a CSP subscription).

Which method in this API can be used for CSP subscription?

Comment: The consumption API's are not supported for CSP subscriptions.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/

Comment: @RickRainey is there any alternative for me?

Comment: Not using an API.  Using the Azure portal, open the subscription blade for your subscription (Home > Subscriptions > Your Subscription).  Then, click on Cost Analysis under the Cost Management section.  From there, you can get your consumption by resource, resource group, tag, etc.  Then you can export it to a CSV file.

Comment: @RickRainey OK thanks. Please write your first comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *consumption API's* are not supported for CSP subscriptions.  See list of unsupported subscription types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/).

You could get this information using the portal though.  In the Azure portal, open the *subscription* blade for your subscription (Home > Subscriptions > Your Subscription). Then, click on **Cost Analysis** under the *Cost Management* section. From there, you can get your consumption by resource, resource group, tag, etc.  Then you can export it to a CSV file.

Comment: I moved to an EA subscription but now I have another problem. Please see if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158315/azure-arm-consumption-get-consumption-of-a-resource-group