# azure-arm-consumption: get consumption of a resource group

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-resource-manager

In my Node.js project I am trying to use [azure-arm-consumption package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-consumption/?view=azure-node-latest) to get the current consumption/billing of a resource group. I mean, how much money was spent on this resource group until now.

Under Interfaces, from AggregatedCost to UsageDetails, all of these interfaces contain methods, but I just don't manage to find the method for reading how much money a specific resource group has consumed.

My code:

```
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');
const credentials = MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(keys.appId, keys.pass, keys.tenantId);
const { ConsumptionManagementClient } = require('azure-arm-consumption');
const client = new ConsumptionManagementClient (credentials, subscriptionId);
const cost = client.forecasts.list(subscriptionId);
```

It retrieves the consumption of my subscription divided by date. Now the problem is that I don't want it to be divided by date, but by resource group. Is there any method in [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-consumption/?view=azure-node-latest) that can do that?

Answer (score 3):

Accoring the documentation, there is no available method/endpoint for getting data by resource group. You have to download all data and process them by yourself.

Here is script that will download data using REST (using ConsumptionManagementClient will be almost the same) and sum usage by resource group. Take it as starting point.

```
const axios = require('axios');

function processUsage(data) {
  let usage = [];

  for (index in data.value) {
    const properties = data.value[index].properties;
    const cost = properties.pretaxCost;

    let resourceGroup = properties.instanceId.replace(`/subscriptions/${properties.subscriptionGuid}/resourceGroups/`, "");
    resourceGroup = resourceGroup.substring(0, resourceGroup.indexOf("/"));

    let foundUsage = usage.filter(x => x.rg === resourceGroup);
    if (foundUsage.length > 0) {
      foundUsage[0].cost += cost
    } else {
      usage.push({
        rg: resourceGroup,
        cost: cost
      });
    }
  }

  usage.map(x => console.log(`${x.rg} | ${x.cost}`));

  // Example result display list of resource groups and costs in EUR (in my case)
  // myresourcegroup | 1.2234748382055878
  // DevTestLab | 0.0004314997440000002
}

function getUsage(subscriptionId, accessToken) {
  const url = `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2018-10-01`

  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
  }
  axios.get(url, options).then(response => {
    processUsage(response.data);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

getUsage(
  "subscription id",
  "access token"
);
```

> Reference:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails 
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-consumption/usagedetails#list-object-
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-consumption/usagedetail
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/cs-cz/blog/azure-consumption-usage-details-api/

Comment: I receive about a 1,000 results and pretaxCost is 0 for all of them. When I used the Forecasts interface (rather than UsageDetails) I did see some costs.

Comment: It is normal to see a lot of results because it list all resources and its 'sub-resources' (*like read access to blobs, write access to blobs etc.*) Please look at this. It is possible that your subscription does not support usage API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/

Comment: It does support. I use an EA subscription which is supported by the entire consumption API. There is not difference between the UsageDetails and the Forecasts interfaces in these terms. The UsageDetails  interface does work for me, but for some reason pretaxCost is always 0, although in the Forecasts interface I can see costs (but they are grouped by date rather than resource group).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how the [Azure Powershell cmdlet: Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.consumption/get-azurermconsumptionusagedetail?view=azurermps-6.13.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-4.1.0)
gives you consumption for a resource group,

Then it [ends up filtering the result for a resource group](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/Billing/Consumption/Cmdlets/UsageDetails/GetAzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail.cs#L125).

So in your case use, use the following when calling `ConsumptionManagementClient.UsageDetails.ListByBillingPeriod`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-consumption/filters?view=azure-node-latest#resourcegroups

Comment: I need the total consumption, not by a period. The docs don't show examples to period formats so I don't know how to use it. I tried the list() function but I received about a 1,000 results and pretaxCost was 0 for all of them. When I used the Forecasts interface (rather than UsageDetails) I did see some costs.